# How to get a scrollbar template to display in designer?

Tags: wpf

I am making a Scrollbar template and would like for it to display in the designer. The issue I am having with it is that since triggers determine determine if the scrollbar should use the horizontal or vertical template.

The sample at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742173.aspx does not display in the designer. Microsoft's Royale displays in the designer by assuming all scroll bars are vertical, so vertical bars display properly, but horizontal ones do not.

The default ones display properly in either orientation, and I would like mine to behave like this as well. Is this possible, and if so, what must be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ScrollBars can be made to display properly in the editor by editing the ScrollViewer template instead of just the Scrollbar template.

In order to get this to work, two ScrollBar styles need to be created, one horizontal, and one vertical. Then, in the ScrollViewer Template set the style for PART_VerticalScrollBar to the vertical ScrollBar style, and the style for PART_HorizontalScrollBar to the horizontal ScrollBar style.